# How to change background color of input text field on the basis of dynamic value in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to change the background colour of the input field on the basis of the dynamic float value coming from the database or from another page.

**Code sample:**

```
<div>
    <input type="text"  readonly value="<?php echo $time_per_tag; ?>"  data-ranges='[[1, 14, "#BEFB93"], [15, 16, "#FDEB99"], [17, 17.5, "#FEBE5C"], [18, 100, "#FB9090"]]' onkeyup="checkFilled(event);">
</div>
```

**output:**

[image: here]

Here **$time_per_tag** is the variable that contain value from the database in float. Now  if the value is between(1-14) the background colour will be **green(#BEFB93)** and if between(15-16) then yellow(#FDEB99) and so on...

**JS:**

```
  function checkFilled(event) {

              var inputVal = event.target;
              var inputData = JSON.parse(inputVal.dataset.ranges);
              var color = "";

              for (i = 0; i < inputData.length; i++) {
                if (inputVal.value >= inputData[i][0] && inputVal.value <= inputData[i][1]) {
                  color = inputData[i][2];
                  break;
                }
              }

              inputVal.style.backgroundColor = color;
            }
```

the problem is I don't want to input editable by the user. only **readyonly** purpose. but if I do that code might not be work. I want something like code works without **onkeyup**.

Any kinda suggestion, code modification & implementation is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add your color in the style attribute :

```
<input type="text"
  readonly value="<?php echo $time_per_tag; ?>"
  style="background-color: <?php echo $yourColor; ?>" >
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want input to be read only, maybe it shouldn't be input but just span or div?